# Subtract 2 angles that have degrees, minutes, and seconds

Tags: c

I need subtract 2 angles that have degrees, minutes and seconds typed by operator. The exemple is this: 30 degrees 50 minutes 45 seconds - 10 degrees 20 minutes and 53 second = 20 degrees 29 minutes and 52 seconds. But my code returns 32767 minutes.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int g1,m1,s1; //timp 1
    int g2,m2,s2; //timp 2 
    int g,m,s; //calcule
    printf("Interval1:"); scanf("%d%d%d",&g1,&m1,&s1);
    printf("Interval2:"); scanf("%d%d%d",&g2,&m2,&s2);
    if(s1<s2) {
        s=(s1+60)-s2;
        m1=m1-1;
    } else if(m1<m2) {
        m=(m1-60)-m2;
        g1=g1-1;
    } else {
        s=s1-s2;
        m=m1-m2;
    }

    g=g1-g2;

    printf("%d %d %d",g,m,s);
    return 0;
}
```

The return is:

```
Interval1:30 50 45
Interval2:10 20 53
20 32767 52

------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

Comment: Single step through the program and check the values of the variables... takes a few minutes of your time to find the bug that way.

Comment: You have a problem with `m`.  Perhaps you should look through all your code paths and see how it is that `m` comes to have a value beyond whatever uninitialized number it was at the time of declaration (if it does get assigned a value...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less complicated:

```
secs2gms(gms2secs(g1, m1, s1) - gms2secs(g2, m2, s2), &g, &m, &s);

...

long gms2secs(int g, int m, int s) {
    return g * 3600L + m * 60 + s;
}

void secs2gms(long secs, int *g, int *m, int *s) {
    *s = secs % 60;
    secs /= 60;
    *m = secs % 60;
    *g = secs / 60;
}
```

Comment: `secs2gms()` looks good as long as `secs >= 0`.  Should a negative difference print out "-123 -1 -2" or "-123 1 2"?  BTW: good use of `long` here.  Note, similar problem with `gms2secs()` if `g<0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is ok?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int g1,m1,s1; //timp 1
    int g2,m2,s2; //timp 2 
    int g,m,s,mt,gt; //calcule
    printf("Interval1:"); scanf("%d%d%d",&g1,&m1,&s1);
    printf("Interval2:"); scanf("%d%d%d",&g2,&m2,&s2);
    if(s1<s2 && m1<m2) {
        s=(s1+60)-s2;
        mt=m1-1;
        m=mt-m2;
        g=g1-g2;
        m=(m1+60)-m2;
        gt=g1-1;
        g=gt-g2;
    } else if(s1<s2) {
        s=(s1+60)-s2;
        mt=m1-1;
        m=mt-m2;
        g=g1-g2;
    } else if(m1<m2) {
        m=(m1+60)-m2;
        gt=g1-1;
        g=gt-g2;
        s=s1-s2;
    } else {
        m=m1-m2;
        s=s1-s2;
        g=g1-g2;
    }

    printf("%d %d %d",g,m,s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "This is ok?" is a question.  Append to your post additional information, code or questions if needed.  This area is for answers.